# Differentiating between circular, rectangular, and square shapes

Tags: python, opencv, contour

Given this image,

[image]

, how do I find the number of circular, rectangular and square shaped pipes?
I am using the following filter for now to get the edges of the pipes. Given these edges, I am using Hough Circles and findContours to calculate the circle and rectangular count. But the problem is that the algorithm finds circles inside the rectangular pipes and vice versa. How do I resolve this issue?

```
blur_hor = cv2.filter2D(
    img_bw[:, :, 0], cv2.CV_32F, kernel=np.ones((11, 1, 1), np.float32) / 11.0,
    borderType=cv2.BORDER_CONSTANT
)
blur_vert = cv2.filter2D(
    img_bw[:, :, 0], cv2.CV_32F, kernel=np.ones((1, 11, 1), np.float32) / 11.0,
    borderType=cv2.BORDER_CONSTANT
)
mask = (
    (img_bw[:, :, 0] > blur_hor * 1.2) | (img_bw[:, :, 0] > blur_vert * 1.2)
).astype(np.uint8) * 255
```

This is how the image looks after the filter/mask is applied:

[image]

Comment: There's probably some threshold or score you could fiddle around with. If the same region contains 50% similar to a circle but 98% similar to a rectangle, it's probably a rectangle.

Comment: @MateenUlhaq, I tried finding the contour area and took the ratio of circle area to contour area and rectangle area to contour area. Whichever is close to one would be the shape, but that too suffers from the same problem I have mentioned above.

Comment: Your square pipes look fairly circular which might be a problem. You could probably find a hough parametrisation that can fix this, but it might affect your recall.

Comment: NMS (non-maximum suppression) should help, it will remove overlapping detections, so squares become squares without the inner circles.

Comment: See https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2016/02/08/opencv-shape-detection/

Comment: @lenik You mean the NMSBox module of in the cv2.dnn library?

Comment: @VikramBharadwaj I meant NMS as a concept, does not matter how implemented. It can be done in about 10 lines of python, so there's no much difference.